# Swift 3 - ">>>-" produces NSLayoutConstraint, not the expected contextual result type "Void"

Tags: ios, swift

Since Swift 3 I'm getting this error: ">>>-" produces NSLayoutConstraint, not the expected contextual result type "Void" (aka "()") in my project.

```
fileprivate func configurateCell(_ cell: BasePageCollectionCell, backImage: UIImage?) {
    cell.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(cell)

// add constraints
[(NSLayoutAttribute.width, cell.bounds.size.width), (NSLayoutAttribute.height, cell.bounds.size.height)].forEach { info in
  cell >>>- {
    $0.attribute = info.0
    $0.constant  = info.1
  }
}

[NSLayoutAttribute.centerX, .centerY].forEach { attribute in
  (view, cell) >>>- { $0.attribute = attribute }
}
cell.layoutIfNeeded()


}
```

Comment: Where does this `>>>-` come from?

Comment: I just got into programming, it's part of this open source project: https://github.com/Ramotion/expanding-collection @kennytm

Comment: As far as I understand the >>>- returns a value.